# How to define a javascript internal method that needs to be accessible from inside obj and out

Tags: javascript, encapsulation

I'm trying to fully grasp JavaScript *[inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29)* and *[encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29)*.  Take the following example (*[and here is a fiddle of it](http://jsfiddle.net/j797f335/1/)*):

```
myPage = {
    someObj: function() {
        var x = 0;        

        //PRIVATE: increment by 10
        var inc10 = function() {
            x = x+10;
        };

        //PUBLIC: increment
        this.inc = function() {
            x = x+1;
        };

        //PUBLIC: decrement
        this.dec = function() {
            x = x-1;
        };

        //PUBLIC: output the current value of x
        this.getValue = function() {
            return x;
        }

        inc10(); //as soon as obj1 is created lets add 10
        this.inc(); //as soon as obj1 is created lets add 1 more
    }
};

obj1 = new myPage.someObj(); //x starts out at 11
// obj1.inc10(); won't work because it's private, excellent
obj1.dec();
obj1.inc();

alert(obj1.getValue());
```

My question is about the `inc()` method.  I need it to be callable from inside and outside of the object.  Is this the proper way to do that?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that there is a StackExchange Code Review (beta) and this question should be listed there.  I tried flagging it to be in that area but Code Review doesn't appear as a choice.  Here is the link to it: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64556/defining-a-javascript-internal-method-that-needs-to-be-accessible-from-inside-ob  Should I just delete this one?

Comment: No, because it has two answers here. If you think they're valuable, you should just accept them. Btw, to get a migration to a site that is not listed in the `close`->`belongs to` dialog, just flag it for `moderator attention` explaining that it should be moved

Comment: Thank you Bergi.  Good to know.  I accepted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need it to be callable from inside and outside of the object. Is this the proper way to do that?

Your script does seem to work as expected already, you are calling the method as `this.inc()` in your constructor perfectly fine - not sure why it needs improvement.

You could however define it as a local function, which you then are going to export as a method - and have it still available "inside" as a local variable:

```
function SomeObj() {
    // local declarations:
    var x;
    function inc10() {
        x = x+10;
    }
    function inc1() {
        x = x+1;
    }

    // exported as property:
    this.inc = inc1; // <== the function from above, not a literal
    this.dec = function() {
        x = x-1;
    };
    this.getValue = function() {
        return x;
    };

    // initialisation:
    x = 0;
    inc10();
    inc1(); // this.inc() would still work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To call function from inside and outside without attaching it to an obj.

This should work ...

```
myPage = function() {

        var x = 0;        

        //PRIVATE: increment by 10
        var inc10 = function() {
            x = x+10;
        };

        //PUBLIC: increment
        this.inc = function() {
            x = x+1;
        };

        //PUBLIC: decrement
        this.dec = function() {
            x = x-1;
        };

        //PUBLIC: output the current value of x
        this.getValue = function() {
            return x;
        }

        inc10(); //as soon as obj1 is created lets add 10
        this.inc(); //as soon as obj1 is created lets add 1 more

};

obj1 = new myPage; //x starts out at 11
// obj1.inc10(); won't work because it's private, excellent
obj1.inc();

alert(obj1.getValue());
```

Comment: Looks like a drive-by-downvoting (of both the question and all answers). However, I wonder about the value of your answer - have you done any changes to the OP's code (I can't spot any)? If not, you should have considered posting a comment instead

Comment: you are right I thought his was not working so I removed the someObj: function()

Comment: Ah, I see now, you really should have hinted at that!

Comment: In this answer I didn't see any change other than removing the main structure which in my real code holds many objects, not just one, so it's needed.  I was asking if I was calling `inc()` properly.  I didn't see where you answered the main question nor did you change anything about `inc()`.  But I realize now the question is in the wrong forum.  Sorry about that.  But I did accept the other answer since he said I'm calling it perfectly fine.